# Calculating driving time between two layers (patients & hospitals) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, routing, qgis-network-analysis

I need to calculate the driving time (following US roads) from patient coordinates to hospital coordinates. In total, I have ~ 250,000 driving time to calculate. I previously used ArcGIS but now I would like to use QGIS instead (version 3.10) as I am soon losing my ArcGIS Pro license. I uploaded my dataset as a vector layer. The dataset has the following variables (in that specific order): patient_id, patient_lng, patient_lat, center_lng, center_lat. I also installer the ORS tool as suggested in a video.

I am having a hard time adjusting from ArcGIS to QGIS as I am not sure where to begin. What tool/plugin do you recommend?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE, Anna! I think 250,000 patients will be too many records to run through the ORS plugin. How set are you on using ORS or are you open to alternatives?

Comment: Hi @underdark, I am open to all alternatives! What do you suggest?

Comment: Do you already have a routable road network dataset? Do you only need the distance to the nearest hospital or multiple or all hospitals?